# Why I can login aix by password which contain suffix

Tags: aix

Sorry for the weird title.My English is poor,so I want to explain it here.Let's assume that correct password of this aix machine(Version 6.1) is "mypasswd".Accidently I login successfully by "mypasswd2" too.What's the matter?Why I can login by password which contain a suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 8 characters for password in old traditional Unix.  This [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1010741) tells of the old limitations in AIX and the new abilities in the newer versions and how to set them up.